# Is there a way to remove nodes from JSON.NET JObject of a certain type?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a JSON object that's returned from an API and some of the nodes are arrays. Is there any way for me to pull those out of the object completely based on the "type" ?

for example:

```
{ "result" : {
"field1": "value1",
"field2" : [ "val2", "val3" ],
"field3" : "val4",
"field4" : "val5" }
}
```

I'd like to be able to remove "field2" because it's an array.

i'm not sure how to iterate through the object in a way that will give me the type of the object.

I'm using C# and JSON.NET 6.0.5

thanks!

Answer (score 20):

After you parse the data do this:

```
jsonObject.Property("field2").Remove();
```

Comment: i'm looking for a way to remove arrays. If "field2" is not an array, i don't want to remove it. If field3 is the array, then i want to remove that.

Comment: Null safe: `jsonObject.Property("field2")?.Remove();`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer. Since you can use foreach with a JSON Object, all you have to do is check the type and choose to 'continue' or not

example:

```
foreach (var item in jobj) 
{
  if ( jobj[item.Key] is JArray ) 
  {
     continue;
  }
    // do what you would do with other types.
}
```

Thanks!