# Json.net how to remove multiple node from json string after the json serialized twice?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

There is a model here:

```
public class RoomInfo
{

    public string Room { get; set; } // this is a json string

    public bool Opened { get; set; }
}
```

After I `JsonConver.Serialize(RoomInfo)`

There is a new json string:

```
{"Room":
  "{
    "RoomId":6,
    "RoomNo":"101",
    "Price":20.0,
    "IsPayByTime":1,
    "AddTime":20150814135504
   },
  "Opened":true
"}
```

But the problem is I want to remove the `RoomNo` and `AddTime`

As you see the `Room` has been **serialized twice**

Every time I get the result I need to remove the node from Json string, and then save it to database, So I need a hight performance way to do it.

I try to use **[JsonIgnore]** before when it was a Model of `Room`, but sometimes I need these 2 field in my json string, but sometimes need to remove. So I can't use that attribute. that's why I just want to remove it after convert to json string.

Is there any way to remove it use a high performance way? thank you.

Comment: where is this in your Json `RoonName` ?? possible duplicate [is there a way to remove  nodes from JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353267/is-there-a-way-to-remove-nodes-from-json-net-jobject-of-a-certain-type)\

Comment: ``RoomNo``, Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

After you parse the string do the following:

```
jsonObj.Property("AddTime").Remove();
```

Comment: I need remove multiple node, and I don't know how do you get ``JsonObj``, I trying to find a high performance solution.

Comment: @qakmak What did you tried and how are you loading it

Comment: Sorry for my old question so confused you.  Now I update it all.