# JSON.NET - Can't remove a property

Tags: json, json.net

I've got a JObject I'm creating using

`var jo = JObject.FromObject(myObject)`

But I then need to conditionally remove some of the properties, based on some flags, because the API we're sending the JSON to treats certain properties as true, just by their existence, even if their value is false. So in the case those properties are `false`, we need to actually remove them completely from the JSON.

I tried to do the following as per the Newtonsoft API docs:

`if(!myFlag) jo["Path1"]["Path2"]["Path3"]["ConditionalItem"].Remove();`

however that `Remove()` call throws this error:

```
{
  "ClassName": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException",
  "Message": "Cannot add or remove items from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.RemoveItem(JToken item)
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Remove()",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": "RemoveItem Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\nNewtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty Boolean RemoveItem(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)",
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": "Newtonsoft.Json",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

I've also tried to use the `.Property("key").Remove();` method as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353267/is-there-a-way-to-remove-nodes-from-json-net-jobject-of-a-certain-type), but that `.Property()` method doesn't seem to exist for me.

How do I go about removing nodes from a JObject?

Comment: This is really a duplicate.  The value you get using the indexer syntax is considered to be a *child* of the property.  Thus you can use `["ConditionalItem"].Parent.Remove()` to remove the property itself.  The answer to the dupe question explains this.  As to why the `Property()` method "doesn't exist": the indexer syntax returns a `JToken`.  The `Property()` method is on `JObject` so you would need a cast to access it, e.g. `((JObject)jo["Path1"]["Path2"]["Path3"]).Property("ConditionalItem").Remove();`

Comment: Cool. Sorry about the duplicate question. Not sure why it didn't come up when googling, which was how I found the other one. Anyway, got it fixed with the cast to JObject as per your comment. I think that is the clearer version of the code, for someone coming and maintaining it down the road.